# Color ramp on an asymmetric object

Tags: materials, shaders, color, shader-nodes

I try to make a chemical polarity like this:

[image]

I'm not talking about the molecule itself but the red to blue gradient with the white between around the molecule. I made the object with metaballs and transform it to a mesh. I know how to apply the color ramp and make it transparent but I can't work it out how to bend the color ramp to get the white stroke bending and the blue spread to both hydrogen parts.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Shader Setup]
Is this something like what you're looking for?

The Texture Coordinate->Object node gives the X,Y,Z location of each surface. This feeds a mapping node so you can center the red on the hydrogen molecule and scale the overall effect. This goes into a Vector Math->Length node to get the distance from the center of the hydrogen molecule to feed into the Factor input of the Color Ramp.

Comment: That's it! Thx a lot for your help. Very kind! :-)

Comment: If your question has been answered, you can accept my answer.